# Highcharts: How to set dataGrouping

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I have a highstock graph with lots of data in it, I am able to define how the data can be grouped, but Id like the user to specify which data grouping to use and change dynamically between day, week, month etc.

So is it possible to have a button whereby a user can change how the data is grouped, if so how?

There are many undocumentated features, for example currentDataGrouping, but there's nothing to set the data grouping... that I can see any way...

```
series: [{
                type: 'column',
                name: title,
                data: data,
                dataGrouping: {
                    units: [['week', [1]], ['month', [1]]]
                }
        }]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The API has a method to update the series (http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Series.update()). e.g.

```
chart.series[0].update({ type: 'spline' });
```

You should be able to use this API call to modify any of the series attributes.

For instance, you could have two series objects defined, and update the chart to use the one you want on a button click:

```
var seriesWeek = {
            type: 'column',
            name: title,
            data: data,
            dataGrouping: {
                units: [ ['week', [1] ] ]
            }
    }

var seriesMonth = {
            type: 'column',
            name: title,
            data: data,
            dataGrouping: {
                units: [ ['month', [1] ] ]
            }
    }

chart.series[0].update(seriesWeek);
```

Comment: Its a bit arse about face of doing it, should be able to force which dataGrouping to use...

Comment: What are the datagrouping options you want to switch between ?

Comment: Week and Month, possibly day aswell, but the data grouping only chages as the range is changed.

Comment: I may be misunderstanding your requirements, but I think you can just update your series options depending on a button click (see updated answer.

Comment: Sometimes dataGrouping won't be used (if not necessary, why group 10points into 3 points) - in that case setup `forced: true`

Comment: It's actually enough to pass the variable options to update: `chart.series[0].update({ dataGrouping: { forced: true, units: [ ['week', [1]] ] } })`

Answer (score 2):

I have always exactly one timeseries, so this approach works for me (no need to update each timeseries manually):

```
self.myChart = new window.Highcharts.stockChart(pChartDivContainer, {
        title: {
            text: 'My title'
        },
        rangeSelector: {
            enabled: true
        },
        plotOptions: {
            series: {

                dataGrouping: {
                    approximation: 'ohlc',
                    units: [
                        ["minute", [1]]
                    ],
                    forced: true,
                    enabled: true,
                    groupAll: true
                }

            }
        }
    }, function (chart) {
        self.onChartReady();
    });
```

After that it's easy to change the unit:

```
self.setCandleInterval = function (pUnit, pInterval) {
    self.myChart.update({
        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                dataGrouping: {
                    units: [
                        [pUnit, [pInterval]]
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: This worked for me. To suppress, I used `dataGrouping: { enabled: false }`

Answer (score 0):

We tried a Hack around this, where we used Highstock's (Splinechart) [RangeSelector](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#rangeSelector), Event and [DataGrouping](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#plotOptions.area.dataGrouping). On click of weekly rangeselectorButton we catch this event through [setExtremes](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#xAxis.events.setExtremes). Post catching the event approximate it to "sum". If you are using two series than iterate the object.

```
  events: {
         setExtremes: function (e) {
             if (e.rangeSelectorButton != undefined) {
                 var triger = e.rangeSelectorButton;
                 if (triger.type == 'week') {
                     $.each(this.series, function (index, obj) {
                         obj.options.dataGrouping.units[0] = ['week', [1]];
                     });
                 } else if (triger.type == 'day') {
                     $.each(this.series, function (index, obj) {
                         obj.options.dataGrouping.units[0] = ['day', [1]];
                     });
                 }
             }
         }
     },
```

@[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/imsinu9/e34eyouu/)